# Trying to divide just the decimal value and keep the whole number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to divide just the decimal place number and keep the whole number and move the results of that into a new cell. For example i have 1.4 units but the .4 needs to be divided by 12 because that is how much comes in a case.  I need the result to be 1.33 in a new cell.

Comment: .4/12 = .033 repeating. Not 1.33

Comment: How exactly are you supposed to deal with 10 or 11 items?

Comment: Agreed, Ignacio - if you use 1.04, 1.09, 1.10, 1.11 etc then conversion can be made with DOLLARDE function, i.e. `=DOLLARDE(A1,12)` - if you don't use that convention how do you distinguish 1 unit from 10?

Comment: @barryhoudini: DOLLARDE just convert the decimal part to the nearest fraction, not **divide** it like the OP wants

Comment: I don't agree - If A1 = 1.04 as I suggested then `DOLLARDE` will convert that to 1.33 as requested

Answer (score 0):

If A1 contains the value then you can get only the part after the decimal point with `=A1-INT(A1)`. I'm also led to believe that `=MOD(A1,1)` will also work, but I've not tried it myself.

Assuming that you want to divide this part by 12 and that you're not, somehow, looking for the answer to be 1.33 when A1 is 0.4 (as pointed out in the comments) - then I would use `=(A1-INT(A1))/12` in the appropriate cell.

Comment: That would not give the answer that the OP says is needed. The needed answer is 1.33 not 1.033

Comment: It's not entirely clear what formulae the OP is using because, as you rightly pointed out, 0.4/12 isn't 1.33. I'll modify that bit to ensure it doesn't detract from the answer.

Comment: I know I can receive the correct result by having the decimal number in a different cell as a whole number and dividing it then add it to the whole number in a new cell I am trying to simplify the spreadsheet for the users

Comment: @Richard I answered below, but feel free to incorporate my answer into yours (to cover the scenario where the OP actually does want 1.33) and I'll delete mine.  Your answer is as right as my one, and we really don't need two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but this will give you the answer you want:

```
=MOD(A2,1)/1.2+INT(A2)
```

So `mod(a1/1)` just takes the decimal part of the number in A2

I am dividing by 1.2 because you want .33 instead of .033

Then adding back to the integer part of A2

If `A2 = 1.4`, then the contents of the cell with this formula will equal 1.33

Comment: This works if the items are shipped by a count of 12,but I have different items that are shipped in to us in various amounts.  How can I change the formula for a six count which would equal 1 full case, or a 36 count to equal 1 full case. Or a 4 count to equal 1 full case.